# Is it possible to access redux store state in same render function as <Provider />

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux

So what I mean here is:

```
const App = () => {
  return (
    <Provider store={store}>
      <h1>{store.state.title}</h1> // For example
    </Provider>
  );
}
```

So in the example above I'm trying to access the `title` prop in state.

Comment: What's the problem? Why can't you access it?

Comment: Sure, since `store` seems to be a locally accessible variable here :)

Comment: This would be one-time access. If a reducer mutates the `title` App would not be rerendered.

Comment: Normally one wraps `<App>` with `<Provider>`, not vice versa, like you.

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can use `store.getState()`

So in your case will be:

```
const App = () => {
  const currentStore = store.getState()
  return (
    <Provider store={store}>
      <h1>{currentStore.title}</h1> // For example
    </Provider>
  );
}
```

Comment: Will this then also update as the state changes? Or is getState() a one time snap-shot of the state in that moment in time?

Comment: `getState()` its a one time snap-shot. If you prefer to update in state changes, you'll have to create a new component inside the `App`, and that component should use the `connect` from `react-redux`

Answer (score 1):

This is XY problem. In order to update `<h1>` with new value, `<Provider>` would have to be re-rendered. Instead, `<h1>{store.state.title}</h1>` should be moved to separate connected component:

```
const Title = connect(...)(({ title }) => <h1>{title}</h1>;
```

And used as such:

```
<Provider store={store}>
  <Title/>
</Provider>
```